# C++ Is it reasonable having an interface class inherits from a concrete class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

In C++ is it reasonable having an interface class inherits from a concrete class? Is this bad deign smell?

I have an interface which defines a behaviour, and a inherited class which defines an implementation.

Now I have another class and I want to state *"Whoever inherits from this class need to specify behavior **X**, and defines this behavior **Y** which alread has a valid default implementation"*.

Is it correct practice this kind of implementation? I'm confused about this abstract/concrete mixing.

```
class IBase
{
public:
   virtual ~IBase(){}

   virtual void method1() = 0;
}

class ConcreteBase : IBase
{
public:
  ConcreteBase(){}

  void method1() override { // some impl; }
}

class ISpecialized : ConcreteBase
{
public:
   // Here I don't need virtual destructor

   void method2() = 0;
}

class ConcreteSpecialized : ISpecialized
{
public:
   ConcreteSpecialized(){}

   void method2() override { // some impl. }
}
```

Comment: This code is certainly legal, but I would argue that `ISpecialized` no longer qualifies to be called an interface.  It's polymorphic, but cannot be used in the same ways that a pure interface can.

Comment: You're right, it's just an abstract class. Still I'd like to have a clear name reference of "this class cannot be istantiated"

Comment: You can use *Abstract* as the class name prefix, instead of `I`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of having `ISpecialized` extend `IBase`, you should consider having it stand on its own. Then you can use multiple inheritance to make your concrete class derive from both interfaces.

```
class ISpecialized
{
public:
   ~ISpecialized(){}

   void method2() = 0;
}

class ConcreteSpecialized : ConcreteBase, ISpecialized
{
public:
   ConcreteSpecialized(){}

   void method2() override { // some impl. }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The language allows it, it's clear and to the point, and you can use the `override` annotation which will help you should you ever refactor to another approach. I'd consider renaming `ISpecialized` though, if you're using `I` to specify an interface.

So other than the unnecessary `~IBase(){}` there's nothing wrong at all with your approach.

If you want a `virtual` destructor then use

```
virtual ~IBase() = default;
```

i.e. *don't* define it explicitly.

Comment: Why unnecessary. How can I properly use polymorphism correctly wihtout a virtual destructor.

Comment: @Moia: And how is your destructor virtual?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't noticed at all I missed virtual specifier

Answer (score -1):

Strictly from a software design point of view, I would not recommend on doing so.

There is no added benefit to `ISpecialized` inheriting from the `ConcreteBase` rather than the `IBase` class, since in both cases the interface will define the exact same set of methods. An interface is something you'd expect to be **abstract**.

If there is no direct relationship between the two interfaces, I would also recommend considering Mark's answer. In such case, it's better to separate them, thus allowing oneself to inherit a concrete implementation of the first one, while using only the definitions from the other.